# Trouble Accessing Data Added In Server Code from the Client

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I'm doing some intro Meteor stuff, and I'm having trouble getting the correct values from my Collection. I'm trying to track ownership of the central site, as claimed by a button. The program is currently just an extension of the Try Meteor task tutorial. Anyways, here's the HTML and JS:
    --------------HTML------------

```
<head>
<title>Todo List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
    <h1>Todo List</h1>
    <form class="new-task">
        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Type to add new tasks" />
    </form>
    {{> ownerclaim}}
    <h4>Current owner: {{ownerget}}</h4>
    </header>

    <u1>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
    </u1>

    {{> loginButtons}}
  </div>
</body>

<template name="task">
  <li class="{{#if checked}}checked{{/if}}">
  <button class="delete">&times;</button>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" class="toggle-checked" />
  <span class="text">{{text}}</span>
  </li>
</template>

<template name="ownerclaim">
    <button class="claim">Claim website</button>
</template>

<template name="ownership">
    <span class="text">{{text}}</span>
</template>
```

-----------JS---------------

```
OwnerC = new Mongo.Collection("owner");
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");


if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe("own");
  console.log(OwnerC.findOne({}));
  Session.set("currentOwner", OwnerC.findOne({}));
  Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: function () {
        return Tasks.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
    },
    ownerget: function () {
      console.log("JOHNNN");
      console.log(Session.get("currentOwner"));
      return Session.get("currentOwner");
    }
  });
  Template.body.events({
     "submit .new-task": function (event) {
        var text = event.target.text.value;
        Tasks.insert({
          text: text,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        owner: Meteor.userId(),
        username: Meteor.user().username
        });
      event.target.text.value = "";
      return false;
    }
  });
  Template.task.events({
    "click .toggle-checked": function() {
      Tasks.update(this._id, {$set: {checked: ! this.checked}});
    },
    "click .delete": function() {
      Tasks.remove(this._id);
    }
  });
  Template.ownerclaim.events({
    "click .claim": function() {
      OwnerC.update({}, {$set: {text: Meteor.user._id}});
    }
  })
  Accounts.ui.config({
      passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_ONLY"
  });
}

if(Meteor.isServer) {
    console.log("YOYOYOYOYOYO");  
  Meteor.startup( function(){
    console.log("YOYO");

    OwnerC.insert({
      text: "none",
      createdAt: new Date(),
      owner: "0",
      username: "0"
    });
    console.log(OwnerC.findOne({}));
    Meteor.publish("own", function() {
      return OwnerC.find({});
    });
  });
}
```

For some reason, my server logs are showing OwnerC to contain the object, but the client logs are showing it as an empty Collection, and findOne in the client is returning undefined. Anyone know where I'm going wrong?